# Laravel Blade, Yield a default partial appears to have stopped working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

This has been working fine before, but I just updated all my composer files and now I'm having a bit of an issue with Laravel Blade. Laravel version is `5.4.28`.

I have this partial (`calculator/leopardgeckos/partials/ogtags.blade.php`):

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://reptimatecalculator.com" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1795251550755689">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://reptimatecalculator.com" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
<meta property="og:title" content="ReptiMate - Leopard Gecko &amp; African Fat Tail Gecko Genetics Calculator" />
<meta property="og:description" content="ReptiMate Calculator was built from the ground up to create an accurate genetics calculator for Leopard Geckos & African Fat Tailed Geckos. You'll get a list of outcomes including percentage chance of recessive genes being carried over, a punnet square of genetics and also a percentage table denoting likelihood of certain combos hatching." />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ url('images/reptimate-og-image.jpg') }}" />
```

And I'm trying to call it in my layout file like so:

```
@yield('ogtags', View::make('calculator.leopardgeckos.partials.ogtags'))
```

So if nothing is set in the `ogtags` section in other template files, it defaults to this partial.

However, what it's actually doing is printing this to the screen:

[image]

I can't work out what's causing my error, this has been working fine for a while now. Has anyone else come across this at all?

Comment: They added it so content passed to yield is escaped, please update to newest laravel to receive fix. https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19884

Comment: @David As above, I updated today and this is why I now have this issue

Comment: Oh hang on maybe i need to clear cache's etc

Comment: Nope, no luck :(

Comment: Have you tried just using `view` instead of `View::make`? It should not escape it if it's an instance of the view contract.

Comment: @David Yeah had the exact same issue. Could only fix it using the below :/

Comment: Ah it appears it's an unreleased update, sorry. I assume they'll release it as a tagged version soon: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/CHANGELOG-5.4.md

Comment: Oh yeah! haha. Hopefully this weekend this'll be released. Thanks @David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I'm updating this now as Taylor has tagged the updates to the framework. In v5.4.28 there was a change noted as `"Escape default value passed to @yield directive"` which is referenced here - https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19643

The below will likely still work but you should be able to pass `View` or `View::make` (haven't tested yet) as the second parameter like I have in my original question without any troubles now.

I've managed to fix this by changing this line:

```
@yield('ogtags', View::make('calculator.leopardgeckos.partials.ogtags'))
```

to:

```
@yield('ogtags', new Illuminate\Support\HtmlString(view('calculator.leopardgeckos.partials.ogtags')))
```

Answer (score -2):

Should be:

```
new Illuminate\Support\HtmlString(View::make('calculator.leopardgeckos.partials.ogtags')

@yield('ogtags', new Illuminate\Support\HtmlString(View::make('calculator.leopardgeckos.partials.ogtags'))
```

Comment: @yield('ogtags', new Illuminate\Support\HtmlString(View::make('calculator.leopardgeckos.partials.ogtags')))

Comment: @AndyHolmes let try then comment :|

Comment: My point is that my answer works fine, and theres no real difference apart from you adding more code than required